# Understanding the JWT token for Google OAuth2

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-oauth

ETA 2:

I was able to figure out all this using publicly-available documentation and my SO's extensive knowledge of cryptography, along with a convenient code example on MSDN that handled the most important part of OAuth2 implementation - verifying the integrity of the signed JWT.

[I detailed in a three-part series on my blog.](http://www.abettergeek.com/web-development/the-big-picture-google-authentication-using-oauth2-and-asp-net-c/)

The critical component is verifying the integrity of the JWT response from your OAuth2 provider - many devs fail to implement this properly due to a poor understanding of cryptographic functions, which is why public documentation from various providers (including Google) recommend using a pre-existing library to handle authentication.

The problem is that DotNetOpenAuth hasn't been updated in **years**, and I don't recommend using an aging library for authentication, since there's no telling what security holes may remain unpatched.

The verification component in C# makes use of RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter.VerifySignature, and t[he sample code in the MSDN article on this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h05c7e2.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_3) is pretty much verbatim what you need to use to ensure that a signed JWT is valid and has not been intercepted by a malicious third party.

ETA:

I am posting this on Stack Overflow due to the fact that Google specifically directs users to Stack Overflow using the google-oauth2 tag for questions, help, and support regarding Google's OAuth2 API. The migration to Stack Overflow for all Google OAuth2 support was implemented in March 2013, as seen in this announcement:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/oauth2-dev

Scenario:

New ASP.NET C# application with third-party user signon. I'm first implementing Google OAuth2 and will then move on to other services (Facebook, generic OpenID, etc.). I know that there are existing libraries for C#, but I'd like to avoid using third-party libraries if possible.

After a long time reading the OAuth2 documentation for Google and figuring out the JWT spec, I've gotten pretty far. However, I'm trying to make sure I understand the third segment of the Base64-encoded JWT that is returned by Google once the user has allowed my application to use their account.

First two segments are just Base64-encoded plaintext. Got that much; that was easy to decode and parse with JavaScriptSerializer. What I'm stuck on is the third segment, which as I understand it needs to be used to verify the Google JWT as valid and untouched by any malicious code.

I've been trying to use OpenSSL to decode the binary Base64-decoded segment before going into C# to write the code for my application, but I'm unable to decode or verify the content with Google's public certificate.

Is there any decent documentation on C# and Google authentication? All I can find is examples using DotNetOpenAuth or other libraries.

Comment: You can probably look at the source code of DotNetOpenAuth.

If you are implementing production code I strongly recommend you use an existing library. It is too easy to make a mistake and create a security risk, don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I was kinda hoping for some clear information on this. Stackoverflow is the official support for Google's OAuth2 API now, which is why I posted here... DotNetOpenAuth isn't being maintained anymore. I don't want to use it.

Comment: If you want to know what is used by StackOverflow itself, you should post to meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/oauth2-dev Google moved support for their OAuth2 implementation to Stack Overflow months ago. I did exactly what that link says to do to get help.

Comment: *DotNetOpenAuth isn't being maintained anymore*. What makes you say that? active community on google groups, active nuget, it even comes as a default package in new VS2012 projects

Comment: The lead dev stepped down. The project I'm working on is large, and I want to avoid being dependent on third-party libraries that may eventually dissolve and stop being maintained.

Comment: I use this library a lot, do you a have link where that was announced? I'd like to make sure as well.

Comment: nvm found it http://blog.nerdbank.net/2013/06/moving-on-dotnetopenauth-in-search-for.html

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Pluralsight account, there is an excellent course by Dominick Baier that has [a section that covers this](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=oauth2-json-web-tokens-openid-connect-introduction&highlight=dominick-baier_oauthintro-m3-jwt%2a3!dominick-baier_oauthintro-m2-securitystack) (in the "JWT Structure and Format" section).  They have a 10 day free trial you can use if you want.

> First two segments are just Base64-encoded plaintext. Got that much; that was easy to decode and parse with JavaScriptSerializer. What I'm stuck on is the third segment, which as I understand it needs to be used to verify the Google JWT as valid and untouched by any malicious code.

According to Dominick, to get the third segment, you base-64 encoded the first two segments, concatenate them with a period character, and then run through the signature algorithm specified in the `alg` element of the header (which is in the first segment).  Then you base-64 the result and you have the third segment - also separated with a period.

But I should point out that even Google says [in the main documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2):

> The mechanics of this interaction require applications to create and cryptographically sign JSON Web Tokens (JWTs). Developers are strongly encouraged to use a library to perform these tasks. Writing this code without the use of a library that abstracts token creation and signing is prone to errors that can have a severe impact on the security of your application.

Since DotNetOpenAuth does this already, that is probably the best way to go.  If you are looking for a Google OAuth2 implementation that is ready to use with DotNetOpenAuth - you can [try mine](https://github.com/mj1856/DotNetOpenAuth.GoogleOAuth2).  It's had several thousand downloads on Nuget already, so you're not alone.

In regards to DNOA not being maintained, I believe you are referring to [Andrew Arnott's decision to step down as the lead developer](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2013/06/moving-on-dotnetopenauth-in-search-for.html).  That is true, and we wish him well.  But that doesn't mean DNOA isn't supported or maintained at all.  It just means that it is supported by the community, rather than an individual or company.  You should be able to continue to get help and support here on StackOverflow, or on the [DNOA Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dotnetopenid).

Comment: I tried getting an OAuth2 implementation working with DotNetOpenAuth. I was running into a lot of problems, and also wanted to learn how this stuff works.

Comment: I should add - I'm not going to be doing much at all with the user's info. In fact, just getting their email from the payload in Google's JWT is probably enough. With that in mind, do I still need to use a library? If so, I might just stick with Google's official library.

Comment: That's precisely the kind of assumption that leads to the kind of errors Google was warning about.  Without full validation, an attacker could get through.  Again, I strongly suggest you watch Dominick's video on Pluralsight.  He talks alot about Google specifically.

Comment: The difference between the [official library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2) and [my implementation](https://github.com/mj1856/DotNetOpenAuth.GoogleOAuth2) is that I am specifically targeting [`OAuthWebSecurity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.webpages.oauth.oauthwebsecurity.aspx), which comes in the ASP.NET MVC4 templates.  Google's library can be used from anywhere, and the samples show a console app.  Both implementations have dependency on DotNetOpenAuth.

Comment: I will watch that video (if it's free) - thanks for the link. Are you saying Google's library uses DNOA too?

Comment: Yes, Both use DNOA.  You can see that in their samples.  Pluralsight isn't free, but you can try it for free for 10 days, which should be enough time to watch that video and check out their other courses.  Click the "Free Trial" link towards the middle-right of their [home page](http://pluralsight.com).  The video is ["Introduction to OAuth2, OpenID Connect and JSON Web Tokens (JWT)"](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=oauth2-json-web-tokens-openid-connect-introduction).

Comment: Note the author of the Pluralsight tutorial video, Dominick Baier, also recently spoke in Oslo NDC 2013, his shorter video is up on Vimeo:  https://vimeo.com/68331687   and here is his slide deck: https://speakerdeck.com/leastprivilege/oauth2-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-ndc-oslo-2013      I too recommend viewing the video, but the Pluralsight is a bit more robust (but they must sign up, etc, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Follow the main OAuth 2 documentation:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

If you need good examples try to find Java examples, they might help since the languages are relatively close.